# android::Where to set alarm(in onCreate or not)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am setting alarm by following code

```
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmReceiverIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmReceiverIntent, 0);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Is it correct to put this code in onCreate?

because, when i open my app again and again, the same code runs multiple time,Do the code overrides itself? or create multiple alarm specified time?

Thanks.

Comment: Since everytime onCreate will be called your alarm code does get overridden. However since the time specified for the alarm is the same everytime, there would not be any difference due to this. If in case you wish to run this code only once, you can definitely use SharedPreferences.

Comment: @AtulOHolic ,since alarm code does get overridden,there is no need for SharedPreferences,Thanks

Comment: also if i did not use SharedPreferences,alarm code does get overridden and alarm is fired everytime,if alarm-time is before the current time,so using SharedPreferences is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

put in this code in to a function and when you want to set alarm then call that function

```
private void setAlarm()
{

    AlarmManager alarmMgr =
    (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmReceiverIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
    alarmReceiverIntent, 0);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code:
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TimePicker myTimePicker;
    Button buttonstartSetDialog;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    final static int RQS_1 = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textAlarmPrompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

        buttonstartSetDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startAlaram);
        buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
                openTimePickerDialog(false);

            }
        });

    }

    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                onTimeSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), is24r);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");

        timePickerDialog.show();

    }

    OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
                // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            setAlarm(calSet);
        }
    };

    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

        textAlarmPrompt.setText("\n\n***\n" + "Alarm is set "
                + targetCal.getTime() + "\n" + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);

    }  
}
```